# How to access local variable inside the block if there is a block level variable with the same name in c++?

Tags: c++, variables, scope

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    int a = 20;     // want to access this variable
    
    {
        int a = 30;
        
        cout << a << endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to access the local variable inside the block if there is a block-level variable with the same name

Comment: If it was at namespace scope you could get at it, but you're out of luck with two local variables. One of them has to get a new name.

Comment: If this is an accurate representation of what you are trying to do, then you are out of luck.

Comment: before declaring the inner `a`, do a `auto& outer_a = a;` Then you can do `cout << outer_a << endl`.

Comment: Why do you want this? Shadowing is the cause of many bugs. Just compile with `-Werror=shadow` and fix all cases of shadowing.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings so that it warns you about shadowed variables. Then basically don't shadow variables.

Comment: Also, if you are now to claim that "my code is much larger than this", then that still is not a valid reason, given this is 2023 and there are many programming tools that allows you to automatically refactor code and rename variables.

Comment: @Bharat2044 `In java, we can access using this keyword. ` No, we cannot. We cannot even hide names in inner block scopes in Java. In your Java example, the outer name is an instance variable. You can do the same thing in C++ with member variables and the keyword `this`. But your question is not about member variables.

Comment: @Raymond Chen

**Is there any way to access it without storing it in a new variable?**

**In java, we can access using this keyword.**

Comment: @Bharat2044 `this` what? `this` is used from within an instance to access members. Create a class and you can do the same in C++ like eerorika said

Comment: My Java is more than 15 years stale, but back in my day `this` helped disambiguate class members from locals. It had no magic to untangle local variables from other local variables. I have a hard time seeing such a fundamental change to the language being made even after decades.

Comment: Side note: What Raymond Chen suggested doesn't create a new variable. That's a [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference), and references are best thought of as aliases, an additional name for an existing variable. Behind the scenes, a reference might be implemented with a pointer, but for something as simple as this, the compiler's much more likely to save everybody the time and memory by directly using the aliased variable in the compiled output.

Comment: @user4581301   Yes, and that's possible in C++ too.   Difference is that C++ doesn't force object-oriented approaches on programmers, whereas Java does, so some variables are often class members in Java in circumstances where they are not in C++.   Either way, use of `this` does not address the concern asked about here in C++ - which is a name within an inner scope hiding a name in an outer scope, which can occur without an object being in play.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access block scope names hidden by the same name in an inner scope. If you wish to access `a` from the outer block scope, then you must remove the declaration of the `a` in the inner scope.

Technically, you can access the named object using any form of indirection, for example using a reference:

```
int a = 20;
int& ref = a;

{
    int a = 30;
    std::cout << ref << '\n'; 
}
```

But, I wouldn't recommend this solution. Instead, I recommend giving a unique name for each variable:

```
int meaningful_name = 20;
{
    int clearly_a_different_variable = 30;
    std::cout << meaningful_name << '\n';
}
```

Comment: In your first example, `ref` could be defined within the block, as long as it is defined before the inner `a` .   Since it is useful for finding/resolving such concerns, you might also wish to mention that most compilers can issue warnings about shadowed names  (albeit such a warning must usually be enabled, as it is typically disabled by default).